# Shared codebase for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, qt, mono, xamarin

I want to develop an App for iOS and Android. For easier maintenance I want to have a shared codebase where the business layer and all the algorithms are implemented.
But I don't want to program the whole application in for example Xamarin. I would like to develop the presentation layer in Xcode and Eclipse and use a framework which has implemented the business layer, algorithms and so on.

It is very important for me that the presentation layer is programmed in the corresponding development environment (Xcode, Eclipse) and the shared codebase is implemented as a framework/dynamic library.

I tried Xamarin (Mono) and Qt for iOS but it seems like there is only the way to develop the whole application in this development environments.

To sum up what i wanna do:

```
                                  /--> iOS App --> implements framework --> .app
shared codebase* --> framework --<
                                  \--> Android App --> implements framework --> .apk

* e.g. Java / ObjectiveC / C# / C++ / Xamarian / Qt or whatever
```

Do you know any development environment or a trick how to do this whith Xamarian?
I googled a lot and didn't found anything which helped me solving this problem. I also know that here on stackoverflow are some questions covering this topic but they didn't completely answer my question.

Thank you a lot for your answers!

Comment: I don't know about Android, nor do I actually know what Xamarin actually is, but you can easily import any library written in Objective-C, C, or C++ into an iOS app and use it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I know it is possible to implement libraries written in Objective-C, C, or C++ into iOS Apps. But is it possible to implement libraries written in these languages in Android too? How easy is it? I guess it's not so easy as in iOS since Android Apps are written in Java.

Comment: Yes, I agree. It is not easy unless you have an environment which is designed to develop in multiple architectures, or is interpretet in iOS and Android.

Comment: You could write your logic in Qt and create UI in Xcode(iOS) and Eclipse(Android). How to link to external libraries is coverd in iOS-Guide and Android-Guide. Nevertheless you could still write everything (even iOS-native Code) in QtCreator. The last compile itself will always be with Xcode for iOS and java for Android. In fact code created by Qt for iOS/Android is bundled as library into the application package

Comment: Perhaps you have misunderstood Xamarin as you still use XCode for presentation layer, and you can use Eclipse or Android Studio or any other Android GUI layout editor to create your Android GUI's. The C# for presentation layer is using native (to the platform) libraries so it's not like the other x-platform tools out there. Your other realistic option is to write your framework in C++ but that's a lot more work.

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh: please refrain from such edits, especially on closed posts where it can delay the automated deletion... as the period restarts at your edit...

Comment: @KarthickKumar [Please don't abuse `code formatting`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/349538)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Xamarin allows you to create business logic in C# and use them for both Android / iOS / Windows Phone. You have to write your view logic also in C#. Xamarin has ported the API for both iOS and Android to C#. You can still use the designer tools from xCode (I guess for Android as well) and use them in your project. But it's true you'll have to use Visual Studio or Mono Develop to create your app.

So you either use the xamarin solution or you'll have to create a cross-platform library in C/C++. For iOS you can indeed just add C++ code. For Android you'll have to use the NDK. You'll have to use JNI (Java Native Interface) to be able to let the Java and C++ code talk to each other.

NDK: https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

JNI Tutorial: https://code.google.com/p/awesomeguy/wiki/JNITutorial

Comment: Thank you for you help! I think I try to use a C++ as a shared codebase first. If it's too complicated to implement C++ in Android, I will make the app completely in Xamarin.

Comment: @electronicMe  
Can you quickly update us what your solution in the end became like? Was ist feasible or too difficult and you ended up in Xamarin? I'm thinking about different topics for my Bachelor Thesis - and a shared code base for iOS and Android might be one of the topics to pick from, but it's hard to find good information about that - Ben